# May two different component manufacturers have the same component maintenance manual number?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

Is it allowed for two different component manufacturer to have the same Components Maintenance Manual number?

Comment: Why does this question have two IFE related tags? Is it specific to IFE, or related to it?

Comment: As nothing in the question relates to IFEs, I've removed the tags. If your question specifically requires information on IFEs, please feel free to [edit the question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/38133/edit) and then update the tags.

Comment: Are you asking about ATA numbering?